# How to pass object, MouseEvent.CLICK and function to trigger

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to pass to function object, const of type MouseEvent.CLICK and function to trigger. In my case:

my class Assistant:

```
    public static function addEventListenerTo(obj:Object, MouseEventConst:String, functinToTrigger:Function) {
obj.addEventListener(MouseEventConst, functinToTrigger:Function);
}
```

and my class Engine which invokes

```
Assistant.addEventListenerTo(deck,"MouseEvent.CLICK",showObject);
```

Please give me advice how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: pass `MouseEvent.CLICK` without the quotes around it, so: `Assistant.addEventListenerTo(deck, MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);` should hopefully work.

Comment: oh and also, you may want to get rid of type definition beside `functinToTrigger` in the `addEventListener` call.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provide there is one **compiler error** (*the one Tahir Ahmed pointed to in his second comment*).

Fixing this by removing the second `:Function` in the first code block:

```
public static function addEventListenerTo
    (obj:Object, MouseEventConst:String, functinToTrigger:Function) 
{
    obj.addEventListener(MouseEventConst, functinToTrigger);
}
```

will let the code compile. (*I wrapped the Method signature to avoid the scrollbar, this is not required to make it compile.*)

The other major problem is a **configuration error** (or maybe a **typo**): the one about [`MouseEvent.CLICK`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#CLICK). (*the one Tahir Ahmed pointed to in his first comment*)

Looking at the documentation it is defined to have the value `"click"` (a String literal following the AS3 convention of the lowercase constant name). So to pass it to your method you can either put in a reference to the constant by writing `MouseEvent.CLICK` (without the `"`s around it) or reach the same goal with passing its value by writing `"click"`.
As using the reference will prevent mistyping because the compiler checks it, the first approach should be preferred.

So calling the Method should look like this:

```
Assistant.addEventListenerTo(deck, MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);
```

If you want to know why your version didn't work you should read a simple  introduction to AS3 Events and EventDispatchers. As a short hint: if deck would dispatch an Event that has its `type` property set to `"MouseEvent.CLICK"` your listener would get fired.

While you are at it, you could improve the *quality* of your code by to major things:

the first one is about avoiding getting runtime Errors and prefering compile time errors: Not every instance of type [`Object`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) has a method called `addEventListener`. In your current code, when you pass an instance to `Assistant.addEventListenerTo` as first parameter, that doesn't have this method (e.g. `{}` or an instance of type `Array`), the error will get thrown while your swf is displayed and it might stop displaying anything and might show an error message to the user.
If the type of the parameter is [`IEventDispatcher`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html) instead, the compiler will already tell you that you passed an incompatible instance.

The second one is about names and conventions, which helps other developers to read your code (an having more fun helping you).

- what you called `MouseEventConst` is called an event type in AS3, which provides a better name for a parameter, as it being a String nobody stops anybody from passing contants of other event types like [`Event`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html)
- the `functionToTrigger` is what is called a listener (or event listener)
- the first letter of parameter names should be lower case

So if I would have written the static method it would look like this:

```
import flash.events.*;

public class Assistent{

    public static function addEventListenerTo
        (dispatcher:IEventDispatcher, eventType:String, listener:Function)
    {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(eventType, listener);
    }
}
```